# Calculate the distances between pairs of points in r

Tags: r, distance, rbind, cbind

Lets say I have generated 10 random points

```
x <- runif(10, min = -10, max = 10)
y <- runif(10, min = -10, max = 10)
```

and I want to calculate the distances between each pair of points.
so I use

```
d <- dist(cbind(x,y))
```

and I got a nice 9*9 matrix.

However, if I use

```
d1 <- dist(rbind(x,y))
```

I only got 1 number as the result.

Can anyone explain this for me?

Comment: The help page `?dist` says it computes distances between rows. `rbind` binds two vectors making two rows. If you have only two rows, there's only one distance for `dist` to compute.

Comment: that explains everything! thank you very much!

Comment: You can upvote the full answer written by fishtank below if it's useful, using the arrow on its left. If it answers your question, you can click the checkmark there to "accept" it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`rbind(x,y)` has 2 rows, 10 columns and is interpreted as 2 points in 10-dimensional space. `dist(rbind(x,y))` is calculating the Euclidean distance between these 2 points.